# Property and class at the same time?

Tags: c#, excel, oop, properties, epplus

Trying to understand EPPlus's API and there is a class "ExcelPackage" it is got a property "Workbook". What is a property value? How can a property be a class at the same time?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The property `Workbook` is of type `ExcelWorkbook`. There is nothing doubled here. Anyway you may have a property with the same name as a class. The compiler is smart enough to differ the one from the other. It's aobsolutely okay to do that.

Comment: The property value is of type `ExcelWorkbook`.

Comment: A Property of a class is basically three things: 1. a (private) "backing field" , 2. a (public) getter , 3. a (public) setter. The type of the backing field is the class or type of the property. It is returned by the getter and set by setter. C# has syntactic sugar that let's you define all of this in one line. For example `public ExcelWorkbook Workbook {get; set;}` will create a private backing field of type `ExcelWorkbook`, public getter (which returns said field) and public setter for you.

Comment: ^^ So the "value" of a property is the specific instance of the type that the backing field references. Which means:yes it's both at the same time. It is an instance of class. Like your car is one specific instance of that model of cars which is in your property (pun intended). So your car is both a car of that model _and_ yours specifically.